# How to catch BeanDefinitionStoreException in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, exception, configuration, javabeans

How can I catch any exception during bean creation/configuration in Spring Boot?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more of what you're looking to do (e.g. at what point in the initialization pipeline) and why?

Comment: Sure thing. I have a Spring Boot app using MySQL. I had mis-configured the JDBC properties which led to a page full of exceptions. I would like to catch these bean initialization exceptions and print out something more usuable so that my team can get directly to the problem. In general, this would be for all exceptions happening during bean init time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to listen for application startup failures implementing an `ApplicationFailedEventListener` like this and then get the `BeanDefinitionStoreException`:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationFailedEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationFailedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationFailedEvent applicationFailedEvent) {
       // Get the exception.
       Throwable yourException = applicationFailedEvent.getException();
       // Check if the exception was a BeanDefinitionStoreException and do whatever... 
    }
}
```

Hope it helped! :)